# Upward trend in Residuals vs. Fitted - Violation of linearity?

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, residuals, assumptions, linearity

I am currently working with longitudinal data using a linear mixed model (`lme4` R package).
The linearity plot (fit with `check_model` function from `performance` R package) indicates an upward trend. Would one consider this violation as serious, as the trend is monotonic and does not show a funnel shape etc. ?

For linear regression it is recommended to examine whether fixed terms or interactions between the terms are missing. In the case of an LMM, could the plot additionally indicate that the model is lacking a random effect?

[image: Residuals vs. fitted values]

Comment: You have a discrete outcome (what is it?). It may be better to use a model suitable for the response like an ordinal regression.

Comment: The outcome is a performance score in a test, you are probably right. Could such a model fix the violation? @COOLSerdash

Comment: I'd reckon, yes. Another possibility is to include all continuous predictors as splines to allow for nonlinear relationships.

Comment: Or model as proportional data with a beta regression